# Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found on puphpet PHP 5.6

Tags: php, apache, puphpet

I've been stuck at this error for hours now and I can't seem to find anything useful on the internet about it. The error is the classic

```
Fatal error: Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found in 
/var/www/NavPHP/nav/plugin/log/NavLog.php on line 29
```

[I'm not using Namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180016/simplexmlelement-cannot-be-found-when-working-with-namespaces) so that's not the problem.

It's a project that works fine in production and used to work in my former computer with WampServer and PHP 5.6.2. Now that I got a new computer, I'm interested in setting up a virtual environment with puphpet, but I'm getting this error.

According to Docs, the SimpleXMLElement class should come with PHP by default. I didn't find any important information on `php.ini` and in my phpinfo() there's the following:

```
SimpleXML   Sterling Hughes, Marcus Boerger, Rob Richards
```

Any tips?

Thanks

### Update

Just to add this

[image]

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Cent OS and in this Linux Distribution, the `php-libxml` package does not come as default.

I ended up generating a new machine through PuPHPet GUI and added to the System Package the following packages to be installed:

```
php-xml, php-simplexml
```

Problem solved.

---

For those using PHP 7 and Ubuntu, @MPS solved it by running `apt-get install php7.0-xml` and `service apache2 restart`.

On Centos, we need to install the XML php package. You can try `yum install php56w-xml` or `yum install php70w-xml` if you're using php70w repository for PHP 7.0

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me.
for others using  
PHP7 version: ```apt-get install php7.0-xml```
and don't forget apache restart: ```service apache2 restart```

Comment: For PHP 5.6 it's: apt-get install php5.6-xml

Comment: If you're using nginx restart it by using: `sudo service nginx restart`

Answer (score 7):

I faced this issued and finally solved by run following command :

```
apt install php5.6-xml
```

After it reload and restart apache2 service :

```
service apache2 reload   

service apache2 restart
```

And a PHP restart may be required

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running ubuntu in AWS Cloud 9. Then from your menu bar->Window->New Terminal->type `sudo apt install php-xml`